# UI halts when EditText is clicked

Tags: android, handler, android-keypad

I have four views in my UI, 2 `Buttons`(Start,Pause), 1 `EditText`, 1 `TextView`. The `TextView` acts like a timer which I am updating using a `Handler`.When I am clicking the start button the timer starts and paused when pause button is clicked.It works as desired but the UI halts when I click on the `EditText`.But in the background timer value is constantly running and when I click on the done key on the Keyboard or hardware back button, the timer value gets updated in the `TextView`.Also EditText value is not visible while typing but shows when keyboard is popped out.Seems like this problem comes when keyboard is popped up.This problem only comes in mobile devices.I tested in 3 different tablets and it works fine.I don't know what is this weird behavior for.I know this can be achieved using  `Chronometer` without any problem but I wanted to know the issue in this code. Guess someone might have faced this situation.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="37dp"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="@string/timerVal" />

    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="heloooo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/timerValue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="38dp"
        android:text="@string/startButtonLabel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/pauseButton"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="38dp"
        android:text="@string/pauseButtonLabel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;

    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };

}
```

**Note:** This is a sample code I got from a reference site. My actual code differs from this but the problem is same like this.

Comment: is it ok that you have infinite update cycle with zero delay?

Comment: @Tishka17: do you think zero delay is causing the problem?

Comment: probably yes, because it does all the work in UI thread. Have you got a stacktrace after a click?

Comment: @Tishka17: I tried increasing the delay time but no luck.In the logcat timer value is increasing constantly but it doesn't update it in the TextView.Also EditText value doesn't show up until unless keyboard pops out.

Comment: i have no more ideas except trying to use delay something like 1000 in bost `postDelayed` calls